# Representing a string uniquely using hashCode

Tags: java, hashcode, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create a zookeeper node with unix path as values(like `/x/home/rrs/data0`) , but this is not allowed.

So I thought of generating a hash code of path and then use it to create a node. 
But I read following about the hashcode:

- Hash should not be used in a distributed application.
- There might be collisions, For example, the Strings "Aa" and "BB" produce the same hashCode: 2112

Should i go ahead with hash code or What other options i have for my use case?

Also if i keep the string same all the time , is it guaranteed to generate **same hashCode** every time?

Comment: 'the Strings "Aa" and "BB" produce the same hashCode: 2112' How?

Comment: I don't know Zookeeper. Why is it not allowed?

Comment: I just gave it as an example.

Comment: ZooKeeper represents the node in form of path , that's why it doesnt allows a new node with value as path

Comment: @LutzHorn Hashcodes, by their very definition, are NOT unique. They are a means to be able to sort and quickly look up items in a Map. They should never be used to test uniqueness, ever ever ever. However, the same String would ALWAYS generate the same hash. In Java, the `hashCode()` method returns an `int` hash, which at best gives only 2,147,483,647 possible values.  I can surely come up with more than 2 billion possible Strings. The only way to guarantee uniqueness is to use the String itself.

Comment: @rrs120486 As a possible solution, would it be possible to replace the '/' character with something that Zookeeper does allow?  Maybe dashes or underscores?

Comment: @CodeChimp I know that. The question was: "How do `Aa` and `BB` produce the same hash code of `2112`? What kind of implementation is that?

Comment: Hashcodes produce collisions as you already noticed. If your only problem is a disallowed character `/` - why don't you just replace it by something else?

Comment: @LutzHorn According to Wikipedia, as of Java 1.2 String has used a " product sum algorithm over the entire text of the string".  The algorithm can be found there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same string will always generate the same hash-code.

Hash-codes do collide, the chance that similar (but different) strings will collide is just very very small (that's the generic idea).  Your application should be able to recover (at least not break) from a collision.

What are the nature of the strings? Are they only letters? Maximum length? These properties can be used to generate a better hashcode.  One of the nicest techniques I know of is Zobrist keys. Depending on the nature of your strings, this may be an option.

Comment: The string I am using is a canonical path of file like (/x/home/rrs/data0). Maximum length wont be more than 1024 chars.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are trying to do.

But you're right: Java hashCodes are not designed to be collision free.

If you need some kind of unique identifier you could use a cryptographic hash function (like e.g. SHA-256, MD5 etc.) over your string.

If you just have a problem with some characters in your string just replace them e.g. with underscore.

Depending on what Zookeeper is/does perhaps hashCode is not a problem at all. EHCache uses it and it's perfectly fine there for distibuted hash tables.

It's a pitty, but hashCode of String really *does* generate the same hash code all the time for the same string. This is because it is documented and therefore cannot be changed. (But note: this doesn't include different representations of the same string like it's possible in unicode. But I think this is not a problem here.)

Comment: Cryptographic hashes don't prevent collisions although they may limit how and when they occur.

Comment: @Tim: theoretically they don't. Practically they do. Indeed it's their main purpose.

Comment: Not for a 32 bit hash they won't, cryptographic hashes use much higher numbers of bits.

Comment: @Tim: Therefor I didn't write something about 32-bit hashes (sha-256 is clearly not one). Indeed I would say (without knowing what it is used for) than an interface which expects an integer as a hash has to be inherently collision-safe.

Comment: Question says Java, Java hashes as per the `hashCode` method are 32 bit integers. (Obviously larger hashes are supported for other purposes but for most cases in Java when you say hash you mean 32 bit).

Comment: Yup. This is what I wrote above: Java hashCodes are not designed to be collision free. I then offered a crypto hash as alternative.